# What's the verb for using a stapler to connect to between two or more papers?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

What's the **verb** for using a stapler to connect to between two or more papers?

In a dictionary I found too much and I'm not sure which of them is the accurate in this context.

> to pair, to connect,  to network, to matchmaker;  (**slang**) to
>   staple.

Assuming that I do not want to use slang, what's the correct choice for this context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word you're looking for is ***staple***. It's both a noun, referring to the small piece of metal that's ejected by a stapler, as well as a verb, meaning to use a stapler to apply a staple.

> *Example*: Staple the receipt to the expense form so it doesn't get lost.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/staple

Comment: You can improve this answer by including a link to an online dictionary definition, for example [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/staple), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/staple), or [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/staple).